# Invoke nodejs based REST service from UI5 Cloud foundry App

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

I have developed a stand-alone nodejs expressjs based REST service and deployed in Cloud foundry dev space. The service has an approuter attached to it with authentication and authorization using xsuaa. I am able to access the service using the following app router url (which prompts for credentials. Once I enter the credentials, it loads the data):

https://busapp-router-<***>.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/busapp-node/nodejsapi/post/sendData

Now, I want to invoke this service (the above url) from a standalone UI5 app (developed using BAS in cloud foundry environment). I do understand that same origin policy issues while using direct url. For neo environment, it was simple that we need to refer the destination in neo-app.json and use it with the destination reference. However, I am kind of lost with the Cloud foundry approach. I have created the project using BAS standalone UI5 template and tried with various approaches by referring many blogs, but nothing worked out.

Can someone please guide me with the steps to invoke the above nodejs service from standalone UI5 app. I am confused on the destination creation, how to refer this destination in SAPUI5 app and how the ajax call from UI5 will connect to the actual target using this.

Regards,

SAP Learner

Comment: Can someone please help me on this..